# How to change the text 'Export Options' while setting export=true in display tag in Struts 1.3

Tags: struts2, displaytag, struts-1

I have a table(from display tag) and I also provide the default export option from the display tag attribute for CSV,PDF etc.The default text which gets displayed near to the provided formats comes as 'Export Options'.
Is it possible to change this text(marked in Red) from displaytag.properties file?

[image]?

The edited code is as under 
My code is as under :

```
 <display:setProperty name="export.pdf" value="true" />
                    <display:setProperty name="export.csv" value="false" />
                    <display:setProperty name="export.xml" value="false" />
                    <display:setProperty name="export.pdf.filename" value="Attendance.pdf"/>
                    <display:setProperty name="export.excel.filename" value="Attendance.xls"/>
                    <display:setProperty name="export.banner" value="Export Options" />
```

My edited table is as under :

```
<div id="attendanceDiv" style="height: 100%;width: 98%;visibility: hidden">
                <display:table name="appUserAttendanceList" id="assetUserAttendance" htmlId="thetable"
                    class="tableBorder" defaultorder="ascending" sort="list"
                    pagesize="10" excludedParams="method" export="true"
                    requestURI="/assetUserManagement.do?method=setAttendanceFromClient">
                    <display:setProperty name="export.pdf" value="true" />
                    <display:setProperty name="export.csv" value="false" />
                    <display:setProperty name="export.xml" value="false" />
                    <display:setProperty name="export.pdf.filename" value="Attendance.pdf"/>
                    <display:setProperty name="export.excel.filename" value="Attendance.xls"/>
                    <display:setProperty name="export.banner" value="Export Options" />
                    <display:column headerClass="displayHeaderDecl" class="displayfields"
                        titleKey="disp.assetUserId" style="width=30%" property="assetUser.uniqueId"
                        sortable="true" sortProperty="assetUser.uniqueId" />
                    <display:column headerClass="displayHeaderDecl" class="displayfields"
                        titleKey="disp.name" style="width=35%" paramId="key" property="assetUser.name"
                        sortable="true" sortProperty="assetUser.name" />
                    <display:column headerClass="displayHeaderDecl" class="displayfields"
                        titleKey="disp.location" style="width=30%" property="location"
                        sortable="true" sortProperty="location" />
                    <display:column headerClass="displayHeaderDecl" class="displayfields"
                        titleKey="disp.operationTime" style="width=20%" paramId="key" property="operationTimeFormatted"
                        sortable="true" sortProperty="operationTime" defaultorder="descending"/>
                    <display:column headerClass="displayHeaderDecl" class="displayfields"
                        titleKey="disp.assetNumber" style="width=20%" property="asset.number"
                        sortable="true" sortProperty="asset.number" />
                    <display:column headerClass="displayHeaderDecl" class="displayfields"
                        titleKey="disp.operation" style="width=20%" property="operation"
                        sortable="true" sortProperty="operation" />
                </display:table>
            </div>
```

[image: The resulting table displayed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code on your page:

```
<display:setProperty name="export.banner" value="" />
```

it's default value is:

```
<div class="exportlinks"> Export options:{0} </div>
```

The placeholder is replaced with links to the various export formats that are support.

Comment: When I tried with the code you provided, it works but another issue pops up.The export options such as PDF,Excel and XML got vanished off.

Comment: Please find the updated code above in the edited section

Comment: is {0} filled whit any thing or shown as it is? I used it in my own code and it works perfect! can you share your files?

Comment: It comes as blank.The thing which amuses me is it works well when I don't set the export.banner property explicitly, but as soon as I set it, it gets vanished.I cannot share the entire file but yes I can share the table(Please see the above)